# How to block specific desktop notifications?

Tags: i3, notifications, pop-os

I subscribe to the Boston Globe. I get unwanted news alerts from them as desktop notifications. I never asked for them. I don't want them. I contacted the Boston Globe and they won't help me. I logged on to bostonglobe.com and looked for a relevant setting - no luck. I get many desktop notifications. I only want to stop the ones from the Globe. I know how to programmatically throw up a notification, but I have no idea how to turn off or block specific notifications. And I would like to continue my Globe subscription. I'm running Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS and I login to i3 window manager. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also get the unwanted notifications when I login to the Pop UI.

Comment: This is no longer an issue.  The UI on these notifications changed a few days ago.  (I do an apt update; apt upgrade every night.)  The notification box now has a place  you can click (I forget if it was a tiny gear icon or what) to block notifications from this source (in my case bostonglobe.com).  I still don't know the answer to my question, but my need to know has vanished.

Comment: I'll close the question on or about Oct 13.  Give any interested parties a few days to see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI on these notifications changed a few days ago. (I do an `apt update; apt upgrade` every night.) The notification box now has a place you can click (I forget if it was a tiny gear icon or what) to block notifications from this source (in my case bostonglobe.com). I still don't know the answer to my question, but my need to know has vanished.